A subtlety about a proof that if $n$ is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational?
I am trying to understand a subtlety in the following proof:



When they write:

It follows that $p^{2k+1}$ divides $r^2$.
The factorization of $r^2$ into prime numbers involves only even powers of primes, and so we may deduce that $p^{2k+2}$ divides $r^2$.

Why can we assume that the $k$ in the first quote is the same as the in the second quote? Shouldn't it be something like:

It follows that $p^{2k+1}$ divides $r^2$.
The factorization of $r^2$ into prime numbers involves only even powers of primes, and so we may deduce that $p^{2k'+2}$ divides $r^2$.

Where k is not necessarily equal to $k'$?

Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post.

Are most of those $r$s meant to be $p$?

Hi! You twice typed $r^{2k+1}$ when you presumably meant $p^{2k+1}$. ¶ More substantively, the idea is that the factorization of $r^2$ must contain $p$ to an even power. So if we know that it contains, say, $p^7$ (at least), then it must also contain $p^8$. It cannot contain only $p^6$ or any lower even power, because then it would not contain $p^7$. So we must bump the $2k+1$ up by $1$.

@ljfirth Corrected.

I agree with @ArturoMagidin that it would be better to type the quoted text in, rather than relying on an image. It is not that long and the MathJax is not too arduous. By the way, what is the source?

Apparently from John Howie's Real Analysis?

@BrianTung Yes.

Please add the tag elementary-number-theory

If $p^{2k+1}$ divides $r^2$ and if the prime factorization of $r^2$ only has even powers of primes, then we can say $p^{2m}$ appears in the factorization for some $m$. But then $p^{2k+1}$ divides $p^{2m}$, so $2k+1\le 2m$, but $2k+1$ is odd and $2m$ is even, so there's no harm in saying $2k+2\le 2m$. Thus, $p^{2k+2}$ divides $p^{2m}$ which, in turn, divides $r^2$.

Let's start with a warm-up.
Lemma: The least even integer greater than the odd integer $x$ is $x+1$.
Proof: Since $x$ is odd, there is an integer $y$ such that $x = 2y+1$.  The least integer greater than $x$ is $x+1 = 2y+2 = 2(y+1)$, which is even as just shown.  Therefore, the least even integer greater than $x$ is $x+1$.
At the point you ask about, we have the equation
$$  r^2 = p^{2k+1}\ell s^2  \text{.}  $$
Since the prime $p$ divides the right-hand side, it divides the left-hand side, hence $p \mid r$.  Let $r = p^\alpha \cdot \beta$, where $\alpha$ is an integer and $\beta$ is an integer relatively prime to $p$.  Now we have
\begin{align*}
(p^\alpha \beta)^2 &= p^{2k+1}\ell s^2  \\
p^{2\alpha} \beta^2 &=  \\
r^2 &=
\end{align*}
Since $2\alpha$ is evidently even and is greater than or equal to $2k+1$, by our lemma, $2\alpha \geq 2k+2$.  That is $p^{2k+2}$ divides $p^{2\alpha}$ hence divides $r^2$.
